# Express basic authentication for serving static files

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I'm using Express 4 framework and I need basic authentication for serving static files. This is what I have now:

```
app.use('/files', auth);
app.use('/files', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'files')));
```

This works great if I try to access /files but if I wrote URL ../files/somefile.txt authentication is not needed and I'm able to access that file. I would want all the files under the "files"-directory to be accessible only by authenticated user.

Answer (score 5):

It's an old thread but I just came across the same issue. I'm using http-auth package to restrict the access to a folder in my public directory.

The middleware was working fine when requesting the protected directory (get /protectedFolder shows the prompt for the authentication), but it skips the files when they're requested directly (get /protectedFolder/file.txt displays the content of file.txt)

I solved it by switching the order of middlewares, I initially had

```
  app.use('/protected', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../../protected')));
  app.use('/protected', auth.connect(basic), (req, res, next) => {
      next();
  });
```

But the correct order should be:

```
  app.use('/protected', auth.connect(basic), (req, res, next) => {
      next();
  });
  app.use('/protected', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../../protected')));
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the following:

`app.use('/files/*', auth);`

Comment: One of the best/simplest answer I have been. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
var auth = function(req, res, next){
    var user = basicAuth(req);
    if(user && user.name == "admin" && user.pass == "admin")
        return next();
    else{
        res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
        return res.send(401);
    }
}

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.url.indexOf('ftp') != -1){
        console.log(req.url);
        return auth(req, res, next);
    }
    else
        next();
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/ftp', serveIndex('public/ftp', {'icons': true, 'hidden': true, 'view': 'details'}))
```

Here is my code, it works fine for me, you can try it.

Comment: Still same thing, auth-middleware is skipped if I try to access straight /ftp/somefile.txt. I tried also express 3 but same thing happened with it. This works okay and asks user/pass if somefile.txt does not exist. But if a file exists, my browser opens it without authentication.

Answer (score 2):

`app.use('/files', auth , express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'files')));`

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)